# Cannot Query sub sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I can't access sub sub documents I want to query the sub documents implement back end pagination so that I can render them in a separate page

I've tried using dot notation something.something.something and even using this ["something"]["something"]["something"] arrays since I recently found out objects are kind of arrays

**This is the model Schema || the child Schema**

```
const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  modelname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 250
  }
});
```

**This is the Bikes Schema || parent Schema**

```
const bikeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 make: {
    type: makeSchema,
    required: true
  }
})
```

**This is how data is stored in Mongodb**

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e13e8edcbbf038c1f9b8e"),
"make" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d40f0b40268d80ac8c30973"),
        "makename" : "{ _id: 5d40f0b40268d80ac8c30973, makename: 'ducatii', __v: 0 }"
}
```

The expected output according to the documentation in order to query the makename ducatii is to do something like this

**console.log(bikes[0]["make"]["makename"]["makename"])**

or this 
 **console.log(bikes[0].make.makename.makename)**

Comment: could you  tell me what is the output for console.log(bikes[0])

Comment: I'm getting the first item in the array since the output of console.log(bikes) is an array

Comment: const makeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  makename: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 250
  }
});


const bikeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 make: {
    makename: makeSchema,
    required: true
  }
})

Comment: Should I remove the required part since when doing that it produces this error  Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `make.required`

Comment: Plus when using Joi Validation what should I still validate it as being  makeId: Joi.objectId().required(),

Comment: yes you can, your object schema will be the same, only makename will be an object instead of string

Comment: Yes thank very much this stressed me so much I was too proud to ask for help but again thank you

Comment: You are welcome, don't be shy about asking for help, we are all here to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embedded document into a document you have to do this like the below

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  // Array of subdocuments
  children: [childSchema],
  // Single nested subdocuments. Caveat: single nested subdocs only work
  // in mongoose >= 4.2.0
  child: childSchema
});
```

Your case

```
const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  makename: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 250
  }
});

const bikeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 make: {
    makename: modelSchema
  }
})
```

then you can access it like

```
console.log(bikes[0]["make"]["makename"]["makename"])
```

Comment: should I remove the required:true since that returns an error

Comment: Thanks this really helped me I was stuck doing it for almost 6 hours didn't realize that I was storing this as a string

Comment: if you would like to add required validation you can do this by adding ref instead of make it embedded document, child will be new table and has relation with parent one to one check this : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note:

1. If the returned result is a MongoDB cursor object, then you can't access via an array index. You'll need to retrieve the item from the cursor using the appropriate method.
2. Your first `makename` field points to a JSON string, not an object. You cannot access the nested `makename.makename` from a JSON string. You must first decode the JSON into an object before accessing the nested property.

Comment: I've tried to parse this using JSON.parse() but each time there is an error something like Unexpected token

Comment: @chuklore The reason is that your JSON is invalid. For example, note that your `_id` value is not enclosed in quotes. That `_id` value is only valid as a string, but the JSON parsing does not recognize it as a string. You need to fix the problem with your data being malformed.

Comment: Thank you for the information since I now want to learn more of Json and how it's stored and retrieved

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with how you are storing your sub documents.

For example:

`bikes[0].make.makename` is actually a string, not a valid object. You won't be able to JSON.parse this string either, because you would have to wrap each key/value with escaped double quotes.

If you are able to store this sub-document correctly, then you should be good to use the object in the way you expect!

Comment: Could you suggest how I would be able to store this sub documents correctly

Comment: Thank you for the information since I've learnt something new today